# Is it possible to find the MAX value of a an already aggregated calculation inside the same view?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have created a calculation in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio that creates a running total per company and quarter, but at a monthly level and this part works fine.

So if company X sold 40 apples, hypothetically, in Jan and then 60 in Feb, then the running total in Feb would be 100 and if they sold 30 in March, then March's running total would be 130 and then in April it would reset for the new quarter.

What I need now is to find the `MAX` of these values, per month across all companies. So if Company 'X' sold 100 in Feb, but Company 'Y' sold 150, I want to return 150.

The calculation I use to get the rolling values per quarter calls on two functions to calculate the quarter each month falls into, as well as the relevant `Fiscal Period / year` ('GetQuarter' and 'GetFiscalPeriod' being the functions).

So my question is, is there any way to find the max at a different level of detail (in this case across ALL Companies) when the value you are looking at is already aggregated at Company level?

I'm told Stored Procedures would make this a lot simpler but the software I use can't call on Stored Procedures, only views and tables.

```
SELECT 
  cm.Company_Code,
  cm.[Date],
  cm.Measure,
  SUM(cm.Actual) OVER (
    PARTITION BY (
      SELECT dbo.GetQuarter(SUBSTRING(cm.[Date], 5, 2))), 
      cm.Measure, 
      cm.Company_Code, 
      (LEFT((SELECT dbo.GetFiscalPeriod(cm.[Date])), 4))
      ORDER BY cm.[Date]
  ) AS Current_QTD_Actual
FROM mytable cm
```

Desired Output would look like the "MAX" field below:

```
+--------------+--------+-----+-----+----------+---------+-----+------------+
| Company_Code | Actual | QTD | MAX | Date     | Measure | QTR | FiscalYear |
| AAA          | 40     | 40  | 40  | 20180701 | Bananas | Q1  | 2019       |
| BBB          | 35     | 35  | 40  | 20180701 | Bananas | Q1  | 2019       |
| AAA          | 60     | 100 | 105 | 20180801 | Bananas | Q1  | 2019       |
| BBB          | 70     | 105 | 105 | 20180801 | Bananas | Q1  | 2019       |
| AAA          | 30     | 130 | 150 | 20180901 | Bananas | Q1  | 2019       |
| BBB          | 45     | 150 | 150 | 20180901 | Bananas | Q1  | 2019       |
| AAA          | 25     | 25  | 45  | 20181001 | Bananas | Q2  | 2019       |
| BBB          | 45     | 45  | 45  | 20181001 | Bananas | Q2  | 2019       |
| AAA          | 30     | 55  | 85  | 20181101 | Bananas | Q2  | 2019       |
| BBB          | 40     | 85  | 85  | 20181101 | Bananas | Q2  | 2019       |
+--------------+--------+-----+-----+----------+---------+-----+------------+
```

As the QTD calculation I currently have is already a rolled up `SUM`, simply wrapping this in a `MAX` function does not work for obvious reasons.

I tried creating a temporary table within the calculation using examples I've seen online, which I then call back into the original table and max that value but I think my syntax is wrong because it never comes out right (I'm still a novice so temporary table syntaxes still elude me quite a bit).

Comment: Can you add some sample data and expected output from them?

Comment: Here you go, I've had to create some sample values: https://app.box.com/s/acbpiw0wfdn562enhksgqc4bmsqeg0bu

I've created columns for QTR and FiscalYear so you don't have to reference functions.

Comment: CTEs are a bit simpler than temp tables. Set your existing query as a Cte then select the max.

Comment: @LVermeulen . . . It is entirely unclear to me what you want the result set to look like.  You should put desired results and sample data into the question *as text tables*.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want the cumulative sum of the maximum values for each month.  If this is correct, you can use two levels of window functions:

```
select measure, fiscalyear, qtr, date, actual,
       sum(actual) over (partition by measure fiscalyear, qtr order by date) as running_actual
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by measure, date order by actual desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't stack aggregates together on the same `SELECT` with the only exception of appying a windowed aggregate (with an `OVER` clause) over a regular aggregate. For example:

```
SELECT
    T.GroupedColumn,
    RowsByGroup = COUNT(*),                 -- Regular aggregate
    SumOfAllRows = SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER ()    -- Windowed aggregate of a regular one
FROM
    MyTable AS T
GROUP BY
    T.GroupedColumn
```

You can however apply them if you warp the former on a subquery or CTE, which also make the query more readable IMO. I believe you are looking for something like the following:

```
;WITH RunningSumPerQuarterPerCompany AS
(
    SELECT 
        cm.Company_Code,
        cm.[Date],
        cm.Measure,
        Current_QTD_Actual = SUM(cm.Actual) OVER (
            PARTITION BY 
                dbo.GetQuarter(SUBSTRING(cm.[Date], 5, 2)), 
                cm.Measure, 
                cm.Company_Code, 
                LEFT(dbo.GetFiscalPeriod(cm.[Date]), 4)
            ORDER BY 
                cm.[Date]),

        -- Add additional PARTITION BY columns for the GROUP BY later on
        Quarter = dbo.GetQuarter(SUBSTRING(cm.[Date], 5, 2)),
        FiscalPeriod = LEFT(dbo.GetFiscalPeriod(cm.[Date]), 4)
    FROM 
        mytable cm
),
MaxRunningSumPerQuarter AS
(
    SELECT
        R.Quarter,
        R.FiscalPeriod,
        Max_Current_QTD_Actual = MAX(R.Current_QTD_Actual)
    FROM
        RunningSumPerQuarterPerCompany AS R
    GROUP BY
        R.Quarter,
        R.FiscalPeriod -- GROUP BY whichever dimension you need
)
SELECT
    R.*,
    M.Max_Current_QTD_Actual
FROM
    RunningSumPerQuarterPerCompany AS R
    LEFT JOIN MaxRunningSumPerQuarter AS M ON
        R.Quarter = M.Quarter AND
        R.FiscalPeriod = M.FiscalPeriod -- Join by the GROUP BY columns to display the MAX
```